# Auto refresh Updatepanel every 5 seconds

Tags: asp.net, webforms, updatepanel

I have an update panel in my master page in a **webforms** application, now I have set this update panel to refresh every 5 seconds so as to reflect an updated count of row items. Some thing like the number of new messages. My questions are:

- Is this the right way to reflect for new row item count on my page every 5 seconds and
- Will this degrade my applications performance in the long run in what
  ever way by constantly refreshing the update panel frequetly.

My label is getting its value from an `ExecuteReader` query from my code-behind.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [updatepanel vs page methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9555203/updatepanel-vs-page-methods)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can refresh after five seconds or on any interval with `Timer` control without degrading performance.

Here's an example with an interval:

**HTML Markup:**

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>      
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <!-- your controls in panel -->
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
    </Triggers> 
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="5000" OnTick="Timer1_Tick"></asp:Timer>
```

**Code-Behind:**

```
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // your stuff to refresh after some interval
}
```